# jQuery не могу получить следующий соседней элемент, помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, jquery

Собственно сам код

```
jQuery(".lk_meny_active ul li:not("+data+")  a").attr("disabled", 
"disabled").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)").addClass("lk_meny_active_no");
```

В `+data+` у меня айдишники элементов - `#item-110,#item-111,#item-112`

Этот скрипт берет li с этими id и задает им класс, но мне нужно выбрать еще следующий соседней id как это сделать.

Пробовал так но ничего не получается

```
jQuery(".lk_meny_active ul li:not("+data+")  a").prev().attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)").addClass("lk_meny_active_no");
```

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $(".lk_meny_active ul li:not('#item-110,#item-111,#item-112')  a").attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)").addClass("lk_meny_active_no");
});
```

```css
.lk_meny_active ul {
  display: none;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li.current.active,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li.current.active {
  background: #2FC7A9 !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li.current.active a span,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li.current.active a span {
  background: none;
  color: #FFF !important;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li:Hover,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li:Hover {
  background: #F6F5F6;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li A,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li A {
  background: none !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
.lk_meny_active ul {
  counter-reset: li;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 33px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li a:hover:before {
  border: 2px solid #2FC7A9;
  color: #2FC7A9;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li.current.active a:before {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}
.bbcode {
  display: none !important;
}
#comments-form p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
.lk_meny_active_no,
.lk_meny_active_no span {
  color: #DBDBDB !important;
}
.lk_meny_active_no:before {
  color: #DBDBDB !important;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vt_moduletable clearfix moduletable lk_meny_active">
  <div class="vt_box clearfix">
    <ul class="menu" style="display: block;">
      <li id="item-110">
        <a href="/index.php/obem-raboty"> <span> Объем работы</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item-111">
        <a href="/index.php/rabota-v-gruppe-vk"> <span> Работа в группе ВК</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="current active" id="item-112">
        <a href="/index.php/ceremonial"> <span> Церемониал</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item-113">
        <a href="index.php"> <span> Размещение сообщения</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item-114">
        <a href="index.php"> <span> Назначение знакомства</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы ошибаетесь. этот код **не** _берет li с этими id и задает им класс_

Comment: кроме того, нужно добавить в вопрос пример разметки html к которой будет применяться этот скрипт, с указанием к какому элементу и что в итоге должно примениться

Comment: @Grundy, ну да, он задает всем кто не соответствует, но как следующий элемент выбрать?

Comment: следующий это какой? (по английски следующий будет - next)

Comment: @Grundy, вот html добавил

Comment: и еще надо добавить к каким элементам сейчас применяется, и к каким еще должно применяться

Comment: @Grundy в +data+ попали допустим #item-111, #item-112, нужно выбрать следующий соседний item-116

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42216/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как надо добавить атрибут и класс ко всем выбранным кроме первого, нужно выбросить его из результирующего набора, для этого можно использовать [функцию `slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Например:

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $(".lk_meny_active ul li:not('#item-110,#item-111,#item-112')  a").slice(1).attr("disabled", "disabled").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)").addClass("lk_meny_active_no");
});
```

```css
.lk_meny_active ul {
  display: none;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li.current.active,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li.current.active {
  background: #2FC7A9 !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li.current.active a span,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li.current.active a span {
  background: none;
  color: #FFF !important;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li:Hover,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li:Hover {
  background: #F6F5F6;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li A,
.moduletablelk_balans ul li A {
  background: none !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
.lk_meny_active ul {
  counter-reset: li;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 33px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #666;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li a:hover:before {
  border: 2px solid #2FC7A9;
  color: #2FC7A9;
}
.lk_meny_active ul li.current.active a:before {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}
.bbcode {
  display: none !important;
}
#comments-form p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none !important;
}
.lk_meny_active_no,
.lk_meny_active_no span {
  color: #DBDBDB !important;
}
.lk_meny_active_no:before {
  color: #DBDBDB !important;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vt_moduletable clearfix moduletable lk_meny_active">
  <div class="vt_box clearfix">
    <ul class="menu" style="display: block;">
      <li id="item-110">
        <a href="/index.php/obem-raboty"> <span> Объем работы</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item-111">
        <a href="/index.php/rabota-v-gruppe-vk"> <span> Работа в группе ВК</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="current active" id="item-112">
        <a href="/index.php/ceremonial"> <span> Церемониал</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item-113">
        <a href="index.php"> <span> Размещение сообщения</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="item-114">
        <a href="index.php"> <span> Назначение знакомства</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```